# Multiprocessing is slower than single core on python

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

I have a proprietary networking library built in python. It's currently threaded, but I want it to have more scalability potential, so the next step is to overcome python's GIL.

However, I've had some issues with trying to implement this. I haven't done much multiprocessing, but I wasn't expecting results this poor, which leads me to believe that I must have messed something up significantly.

These results were run on an i5-10300H (4C/8T) CPU, and 8GB RAM, tested against a local Nginx Server

Without multiprocessing:

2000 requests = 1.4 seconds

Now with multiprocessing:

```
   Spawned Processes   Time Taken (s)

   1                   1.5
   2                   1.6
   3                   1.55
   4                   2.3
   6                   2.35
   8                   2.4
```

I've split up the same 2000 requests, over x amount of processes for each multiprocessing test. It's also important to note that the time taken calculated, starts from when the networking tasks begin, to when the networking tasks end. This was done to ignore overhead caused by spawning processes

The proprietary networking library does have initial overhead cost significant enough to acknowledge, and experiences greater requests/second overtime. However, I don't believe that should result in slower than without multiprocessing. Here's the code I used:

```
def stuffToExecute(something):
    with genericNetworkingLibrary(maxThreadNum=100) as TSN:
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(500):
            TSN.threadFastGetRequest("http://127.0.0.1")

    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as processPool:
        processPool.map(stuffToExecute, range(4))
```

I also attempted to multiprocess this with `multiprocessing.Process(target=stuffToExecute args=(something,))` for the number of processes I wanted to create. And then I tried to manually start them and wait until they were fully executed, but got the same results as the above context manager.

I tried these tests on a desktop computer with an i7 4790k and 24GB RAM, and while the speed was significantly quicker, I still observed the same general trend that with more processes the time taken to execute 2000requests/processes, somehow takes longer.

TLDR; Even though I'm splitting up the workloads, and each process has less work to do, compared to doing it all on one process, this workload is still somehow taking longer than if I had done it without using multiprocessing.

NOTE: Since anyone answering this question doesn't have access to the code. I tried to provide as much information about it to solve the problem. Potential troubleshooting steps would also be appreciated, as it can be hard to solve a problem without testing the solution

Comment: Which operating system? Windows can be slower than linux/mac because new processes need to be spawned, modules imported and a snapshot of your environment pickled and expanded in the new process. This is a one time cost when creating a pool, but can be lots of overhead, especially if your modules do a lot of work at module level (and if your top level script doesn't put its execution code inside of a `if __name__=="__main__"` block).

Comment: The other killer is how much data is passed from parent process to child (and back again) for each task. If its a lot, it can overshadow the benefits of mp.

Comment: I'm running this on Windows 10. There is no data being passed between parent proccess and child process when running these tests. The one time cost you mention isn't taken into account into the timeTaken I've calculated. The time measurements I took specifically only measure how long it takes to run the networking workload inside the process. It doesn't include the process creation overhead